# Не работает аналитика в iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, in-app-purchases, appstore

Несколько дней назад разместил приложение в iTunes Connect. Точно знаю, что приложение уже скачало несколько человек. Но в Аналитике приложений везде показываются нули и пишется, что "Недостаточно данных". Из-за чего это может быть?

Comment: Как давно выложили? Статистика формируется с некоторой задержкой.

Comment: 5 января, 3 дня назад

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данные собираются. Вам нужно просто подождать некоторое время.